# Why does all.equal in R not test for differences per observations where mismatch happen by tolerance amount, rather than the aggregate mean?

Tags: r

`all.equal` in R tests for differences (absolute / relative) for observations where mismatch happen, and then makes sure that it is within tolerance amount. Ideally, it should test all observations where mismatch happens by tolerance amount, and then report the differences... Why is the behavior so ?

e.g.  In the following case, I would expect the result of all.equal to be FALSE, as the first observation in x is not equal to y

```
> x = rep(1, 1000)
> y = rep(1, 1000)
> x = x + 0.001
> y[1] = 2
> print(all.equal(x, y, scale = 1, tolerance=0.01))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: I think his question is "Why is the result TRUE when I expected it to be FALSE?", to which the answer is: "Because the mean absolute difference is 0.001998, which is less than your specified tolerance."

Answer (score 0):

The `all.equal` function returns TRUE if the the target and current arguments are nearly equal up to a specified tolerance, which has a default value close to 1.5e-8. The function does **not** return FALSE otherwise, rather it returns the mean relative (`scale=NULL`) or absolute (`scale=1`) difference.

```
x = rep(1, 1000)
y = rep(1, 1000)
x = x + 0.001
y[1] = 2
print(all.equal(x, y, scale = 1)) # Omit the tolerance
[1] "Mean absolute difference: 0.001998"

mean(abs(x-y))
[1] 0.001998
```

If you read the help page for all.equal, you would see the reason:

```
tolerance   numeric ≥ 0. Differences smaller than tolerance are not reported.
```

**Edit**: Based on Aaron's assessment of the OP's source of confusion, perhaps the `any` function was required:

```
y[1] = 1
any(abs(x-y) > 0.01) # Element-wise comparison
[1] FALSE

y[1] = 2
any(abs(x-y) > 0.01)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I think the source of the OP's confusion is that they think it should make comparisons elementwise rather than in aggregate by taking the mean. That is, having `x[1] = 1.001` and `y[1] = 2` should result in a non-`TRUE` output (in the OP's expectation).

Comment: +1 .. It will be great if one can help with an inbuilt solution that `makes comparisons elementwise rather than in aggregate by taking the mean`. It is needed as expect_equal of testthat library internally uses this API... It is good if the entire ecosystem is consistent, and intuitive

Comment: I agree that the `all.equal` function may not do what you think it should do at first. But that's what the help pages are there for. Websites like StackOverflow are also here as a source of help in case the help pages are too cryptic. I still get headaches after reading the help page of `grep`. But like any language, R has evolved over time. Functions are not consistent, just like English. It's a big potpourri. Bon appétit !